# YA novel about characters in a fantasy novel who must fight to prevent the text of the novel itself from being corrupted

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I found a shabby copy of this book at the library in the early 2000s. The central conceit of the story was that the characters were characters in a stereotypical medieval fantasy book, and they experience people reading this book as being summoned to act out the events of the story.

- The protagonist is a princess in the book, and her "parents" are the king and queen in the book.
- The characters of the in-story book know when their book is being read and what format the book is in. I distinctly recall that a character complains about the book being read on electronic devices because they have to walk "down" as they perform the story.
- The conflict of the novel concerns some kind of corruption to the story; I don't really remember what this corruption was or why exactly it bothered the protagonist. However, the cause of the corruption is discovered by the end.
- The corrupting agent is marked by the color yellow. I don't remember if this was woven into earlier scenes or if it only comes up in the revelatory scene at the end. I recall that revelation as involving the realization that someone is wearing yellow socks.

The book itself was hardcover and I don't know if its condition was due to its popularity or its age. I somewhat recall there being a picture of a girl in a purple gown on the cover.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might be [*Into the Labyrinth*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?180725) (2002) by Roderick Townley.

[image]

The Amazon summary of the book mentions the story being changed around:

> What a relief when the old storybook is republished and the characters who live inside it suddenly discover they have Readers again - lots of Readers - especially when the book is loaded on to the Web. The endless reading exhausts the characters - but that's nothing to the problems they face as strange things start happening. Words get changed around, scenes disappear - and Sylvie and her friends must launch themselves into the labyrinth of cyberspace to confront a twenty-first century evil that threatens to destroy their world.

A quick mention on another site mentions the characters having to run down the screen:

> [In *Into the Labyrinth*] the book is moved online, and they have to run down the screen. They get their dresses caught on the words, etc.

The book is the sequel to [*The Great Good Thing*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?22034) (2001) which doesn't seem to contain the bits about corruption or running down the page.

Comment: I think this is it! The protagonist's name -- and the capitalization of "Reader" -- really rings a bell.